# Using Confluent Kafka Consumer in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kerberos, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

i`m having a problem when using confluent-kafka consumer with kerberos.

I have Kafka running on Cloudera Cluster, secured with a kerberos to authenticate. And i`m developing python app on Linux using Confluent-Kafka, and configure it to connect to kerberos secured env.

But i notice that Confluent-Kafka change the Service Principal in kerberos ticket :

```
from : krbtgt/xxx.xxx.xx@sample.com
to   : kafka/xxx.xxx.xx@sample.com
```

And when i needed the kerberos ticket to insert data that i pull from Kafka into Hive, it`s will give error as the ticket already changed.

I already test the connection using Confluent-Kafka consumer and hive client separately, and it`s working normally.

My python Confluent-Kafka configuration is :

```py
settings = {
    'bootstrap.servers': 'SOMESERVER:9093',
    'group.id': 'mygroup',
    'client.id': socket.gethostname(),
    'enable.auto.commit': True,
    'session.timeout.ms': 6000,
    'default.topic.config': {'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest'},
    'security.protocol': 'SASL_SSL',
    'sasl.kerberos.service.name': 'kafka',
    'sasl.kerberos.principal': 'SOMEUSERNAME',
    'sasl.mechanism': 'GSSAPI',
    'ssl.ca.location': '/home/randomlocation/cm.pem',
    'sasl.kerberos.keytab': '/home/randomlocation/generatedkeytab.keytab',
}
```

is there a way to configure confluent-kafka, so i can reuse the kerberos ticket for another client (hive) ?

Comment: If you want to pull from Kafka to Hive, why not use Kafka HDFS Connector?

Comment: as far i know, kafka HDFS Connector only works with Confluent Platform, currenty i`m using Kafka on Cloudera Cluster. I got it work with "Spark Streaming + Kafka Integration" that support SSL / TLS, but it still experimental.

Comment: No. Confluent Platform includes Apache Kafka... And Apache Kafka includes the Kafka Connect API, for which you can run HDFS connector as part of it

Comment: hi, i just check the Cloudera documentation, and no luck for me. it`s still Unsupported features in Cloudera Distribution of Apache Kafka.

Comment: "Unsupported" does not mean it won't work. `connect-standalone` and `connect-distributed` shell scripts are both there, but you shouldn't run Kafka Connect on the same hardware of the brokers anyway, so it shouldn't matter... My main point is that using just the regular confluent-kafka-python consumer, it is not clear how you plan on uploading data to Hive... Even Spark Streaming would make more sense here